# Unable to calculate the costing amount

Tags: sql, oracle

```
CREATE TABLE Purchase_payment
(  
     supplier_id int 
         foreign key references purchase_supplier_master_details(supplier_id)
                 on delete cascade
                 on update cascade,
     stock_name varchar(25),
     QUANTITY INT NOT NULL,
     Currency_type VARCHAR(15),-----FOR BOTH NATIONAL AND INTERNATIONAL SUPPLIER
     COSTING_Amount INT NOT NULL,
     INTERVALS INT,
     PERMONTH_PAYMENTS INT,
     PAYMENT_MODE VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
     PAID VARCHAR(5),

     CONSTRAINT PAID CHECK (PAID = 'YES' OR PAID = 'NO')
)
```

My query:

```
select 
    supplier_id,
    stock_name,
    QUANTITY,
    Currency_type,
    COSTING_Amount as "Discounted_amount",
    case
       when  supplier_id= 41256 and Currency_type ='RUPEE' 
          then COSTING_Amount=(COSTING_Amount-0.25*COSTING_Amount) as "Discounted_amount",
       when supplier_id=41257 and Currency_type='RUPEE'
          then COSTING_Amount=(COSTING_Amount-0.50*COSTING_Amount) as "Discounted_amount"
       else 'no discount'
    end 
from Purchase_payment
```

This query is valid only when currency is rupee. In purchase table there is also euro and pound so different for scenario can you add all currency conversion in single case statement?

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: So what exactly is the question?

Comment: Please elaborate on your question...

Comment: i want to to add discounted values as u can see in the view im creating !!for purchase_payment table!!

Comment: The column alias as "Discounted_amount"` should come after the END keyword of the CASE statement, not after every WHEN clause. Although as you have already used taht alias for another column you also need to change it to something different.

Comment: By the way, the table DDL is invalid. It's VARCHAR2 not VARCHAR, FOREIGN KEY is for specifying a name for the constraint, there's no ON UPDATE CASCADE, and you don't need to repeat the datatype of the parent column. `supplier_id references purchase_supplier_master_details(supplier_id) on delete cascade` should do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your case syntax is wrong and that's why couldn't be able to calculate the costing amount

```
select supplier_id,stock_name,
       QUANTITY,Currency_type,COSTING_Amount,
       case 
          when  supplier_id= 41256 and Currency_type ='RUPEE'  then COSTING_Amount-0.25*COSTING_Amount
          when supplier_id=41257 and Currency_type ='RUPEE'  then COSTING_Amount-0.50*COSTING_Amount 
          else 0 
       end as "Discounted_amount"
from Purchase_payment
```

Comment: thanks!! but this query is valid only when currency is rupee look in purchase table there is also euro and pound so different for scenario can u add all curency conversion in single  case statement!

Comment: now if we want to convert international currency like euro ,pound  to rupee  then what?

Comment: @DIVYANSHUSINGH, make the conversion accordingly to rate :), however, what you want specify in your question. It would be better if you provide sample data and your desired output

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a problem with your data model. It's bad practice to have supplier IDs hardcoded like that; probably true for the rates as well. What you should do is have a separate table to hold the values. Something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE supplier_discount
(  
     supplier_id int 
         foreign key references purchase_supplier_master_details(supplier_id)
                 on delete cascade,
     Currency_type VARCHAR(15),
     discount_rate number);
```

Include this table in your query, using an outer join (to handle suppliers who don't have discounts for a given currency). Note that it's also bad practice to return numbers and strings in the same column, so my CASE statement returns a zero when there is no discount to be made.

```
select 
    pp.supplier_id,
    pp.stock_name,
    pp.quantity,
    pp.currency_type,
    pp.costing_amount,
    case
       when sd.discount_rate is not null then 
       then pp.costing_amount - (sd.discount_rate * pp.costing_amount)
       else 0 
       end as discounted_amount
from purchase_payment pp
left outer join supplier_discount sd
   on sd.supplier_id = pp.supplier_id
   and sd.currency_type = pp.currency_type
```

Comment: thanks for your valuable input but here we are working with hardcoted values!!

Comment: @WilliamRobertson - good spot on the non-Oracle SQL. As you can tell I just cut'n'pasted code from the Seeker's question :-)